# Can be usable the data if the data transaction still not closed for opened insert operation?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

The transaction is begun with `Data.Connection.BeginTransaction("Insert")` after that, Some insert operation is made. When `Data.Transaction.Commit()` or `Data.Transaction.Rollback()` statements are not called, could be the data added in this transaction be selected? In other words, can I select the data is inserted in this transaction operation without calling the transaction's **Rollback** or **Commit** function?

Comment: If it happens within the same connection, yes.

Comment: It looks like you are using the Entity interface to a database and the statements are part of the library.  You would have to use a different method to connect to the database which probably will be slower than Entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in the same context that started the transaction, you can access anything you have added in the transaction, including from all nested transactions.

It will not be available from any other unrelated transaction (when the first transaction is not committed).